# Creating a FileOutputStream on Android to create a local file, without using Context

Tags: android, io, android-context

I can use

```
FileOutputStream openFileOutput("file.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

from within a Context, and so write a file to the `/data/data/com.example/files/`. If I try to create a FileOutputStream without using the context, like this...

```
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file)
```

... then I get this error: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /file.txt (Read-only file system)`

I am guessing that this is because the using the new() constructor interprets the file name as an absolute path, while openFileOutput() interprets it as being relative to the directory returned by `getFilesDir()`. However, `getFilesDir()` is also a method of Context.

Do I *have* to work from within a context in order to save a file locally, or is there a context-free way to go?

Comment: There is (you can pass an absolute path to the File() constructor), but assuming what a valid path would be is bad.  What would be best would be to discover it from a Context (anything that can *start* your code running will have one once it gets into its lifecycle methods) and then hang onto that String.  It's not like it's going to change during the lifetime of your process, but it could conceivably change with a new Android version or a different device.

Comment: @Chris Thanks! I've used context.getDir() in an instance where there is a reason to access the context, and then I've passed the path to the director to the instance that needs to use it. So I get my absolute path, and I can be sure that it is valid.